# Detailed Requirements checklist?

Tags: requirements-validation

Our requirements are often not detailed enough (for Development or QA). We are starting a new requirement review process that we hope will help rectify this. As part of the new process, we would like to provide Business (and Development) a “checklist” of sorts. It could illustrate the types of things that should be included. A simplistic (and incomplete) example for dates

- Valid date
- Maxiumum
- Minimum
- Does it have to be after other field(s)
- Does it have to be before other field(s)
- Display format
- Conditional display
- Etc.

For each type of field, control, menu, etc. the list would likely vary.

I’d rather not re-invent the wheel. I’ve done some searches, but haven't found anything at this level.

So, my question is: **Has anyone seen list(s) like this that we could utilize?**

Comment: Please make the question more clear, Is the requirements for API , ui , ux? What you mean by date ? Is it Date picker ? In ui?

Comment: Any requirements - regardless of interface, platform, etc. "Date" was my attempt to provide a very simple, generic example of the types of things I would provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can get great guidance from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

and the HTML5 attributes that have come into existance reflect the basic validations you'll be doing, e.g.

- required: Specifies whether a form field needs to be filled in before the form can be submitted.
- minlength and maxlength: Specifies the minimum and maximum length of textual data (strings)
- min and max: Specifies the minimum and maximum values of numerical input types
- type: Specifies whether the data needs to be a number, an email address, or some other specific preset type.
- pattern: Specifies a regular expression that defines a pattern the entered data needs to follow.

More examples at https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ with examples of thing slike `tel` which are cool 'cos they make the mobile phone number display come up.